# How to map Data Flow parameters to Sink SQL Table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to store/map one or more data flow parameters to my Sink (Azure SQL Table).

I can fetch other data from a REST Api and is able to map these to my Sink columns (see below). I also need to generate some UUID's as key fields and add these to the same table.

I would like my EmployeeId column to contain my Data Flow Input parameter, e.g. named param_test. In addition to this I need to insert UUID's to other columns which are not part of my REST input fields.

How to I acccomplish that?

[image: ADF Data Flow Mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a derived column transformation, and there edit the expression to include the parameters.
[derived column transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NruUv.png)
[expression builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhBHo.png)

Comment: Yes, I found that out myself, but anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @[Chen Hirsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21079004/chen-hirsh), **use the same derived column to get uuid values to the columns after REST API Source.**

[image]

They will come into sink mapping:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]